# Is it training too slow or at normal speed? GPU + python + tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, tesla

I am training a "faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco" for custom object detection using tensorflow's api.

I set up a machine at azure with following configuration:

Intel cxeon CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz
RAM 56GB
windows10 64bit
GPU tesla k80 total memory 11.18GB

When i run train.py I get the following speed per second:

> INFO:tensorflow:global step 458: loss = 0.5601 (3.000 sec/step)
>   I1009 19:30:13.254615  5916 tf_logging.py:115] global step 458: loss = 0.5601 (3.000 sec/step)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global step 459: loss = 0.5724 (3.077 sec/step)
>   I1009 19:30:16.331734  5916 tf_logging.py:115] global step 459: loss = 0.5724 (3.077 sec/step)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global step 460: loss = 0.8615 (3.018 sec/step)
>   I1009 19:30:19.350132  5916 tf_logging.py:115] global step 460: loss = 0.8615 (3.018 sec/step)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global step 461: loss = 0.6021 (3.062 sec/step)
>   I1009 19:30:22.428256  5916 tf_logging.py:115] global step 461: loss = 0.6021 (3.062 sec/step)

Is it fast enough or it should be faster as it is using a GPU? batchsize of the config file is 1. When I change it to 2 or higher it runs out of memory.

it takes 3 seconds per step in a dataset of 93 images. Ok... but after training, when I load the frozen graph and try to predict it over all images, it takes 1 second per image.. with the GPU... seems too slow.. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it seems that the training has a normal speed over GPU. The problem with tesla k80 is that isn't a powerfull GPU, so with a better GPU you should have a better performance.

Comment: Thank you David. But here comes the strange thing: it is 3 seconds per step in a dataset of 93 images. Ok... but after training, when I load the frozen graph and try to predict it over all images, it takes 1 second per image.. with the GPU... what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Training and prediction are different actions. When you are training you are making more operations so you need more time to process. So the process of load a trained model and make predictions is faster.